# Error de sintaxis en la instruccion update y no hay error ejecutando en Access c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Buen dia para todos compañeros. Yo particularmente uso clases para todo lo que es moviminto de base de datos y tengo un problema que me da error la siguiente instruccion para MS Access:

Txt = "UPDATE tblUsers SET NickName='Operator', Password='Operator', FullName='Operator', xLevel=2, SttUsr=0 WHERE UserID=4";

Que llamo desde mi formulario con:
int Rsl = BDActions.ExeSQL(Txt);

mis clases de movimiento para base de datos son:

## Abrir y cerrar BD:

```
public class BDConn
{
    private OleDbConnection ConnDB = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EquipmentMaintenance"].ConnectionString);

    public OleDbConnection OpenConn()
    {
        if (ConnDB.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            ConnDB.Open();
        return ConnDB;
    }

    public OleDbConnection CloseConn()
    {
        if (ConnDB.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            ConnDB.Close();
        return ConnDB;
    }

}
```

## Consulta y Ejecucion SQL:

```
public class BDActions
{
    static private BDConn nConn = new BDConn();

    static DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    static OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    static public DataTable Look(string SQL)
    {
        // Obtener Tabla de base de datos
        tbl = new DataTable();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = nConn.OpenConn();
        cmd.CommandText = SQL;
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        tbl.Load(dr);
        dr.Close();
        nConn.CloseConn();
        return tbl;
    }
    static public int ExeSQL(string nSQL)
    {
        // Ejecutar un comando SQL de base de datos
        cmd.Connection = nConn.OpenConn();
        cmd.CommandText = nSQL;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        nConn.CloseConn();
        return 1;
    }

    static public int ExeSQLPar(string cSQL, string cParam, string cValues)
    {
        string[] P;
        string[] V;
        P = cParam.Split('|');
        V = cValues.Split('|');
        using (var cn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EquipmentMaintenance"].ToString()))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = cSQL;
                for (int i = 0; i < P.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(P[i], V[i]);
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Lo extraño es que me da con esta instruccion SQL (que funciona bien en Access) y con el resto de mis instrcciones SQL (muy parecidas) funciona.

He tratado de las 2 formas: la normal y la parametrizada y ambas dan el mismo error. Alguien que haya pasado por esto y lo haya solucionado? Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrado el problema, aparentemente Visual studio hace chequeo de los nombres y si encuentra nombres confictivos como User, Password da este error.
La solucion es o cambiar los nombre en la tabla de base de datos o encerrar entre corchetes el nombre del(los) campos posiblemente conflictivos.
Gracias de todas maneras grupo.

Comment: Hola, te confirmo que sí, hay dilemas con nombres como "user", "password", "red", etc., Saludos.